# How to fetch single row from Oracle in PHP?

Tags: php, oracle, row, fetch, oracle-call-interface

I want to know how to fetch single row from Oracle in PHP?

Chedck my script-:
I want to **fetch single row** from **ITEM_INFO** table & compare that values with  variables **$sku** & **$code**...Logic I applied which works in Mysql but not working in Oracle...

Each time $sku & $code contains diff. values so I just need to compare them with ITEM_INFO table & if it's matches then update the flag for the same...

```
$query_fetch = "SELECT ITEM_NAME,SITE_CODE FROM app.ITEM_INFO WHERE ITEM_FLAG = 'N'";
$stmt = oci_parse($conn,$query_fetch);
oci_execute($stmt);
while(($row = oci_fetch_array($stmt, OCI_BOTH))) 
{   
    $ITEM_NAME = ($row["ITEM_NAME"]);                       
    $SITE_CODE = ($row["SITE_CODE"]);   

    if(($ITEM_NAME === $sku) && ($SITE_CODE === $code))
    {   
              $query_ora_update = "UPDATE app.ITEM_INFO SET ITEM_FLAG= 'Y', LAST_UPDATE_DATE = sysdate WHERE ITEM_NAME = '$sku' AND SITE_CODE = '$code' AND ITEM_FLAG = 'N' ";
                                            $parse_result = oci_parse($conn,$query_ora_update);
    $result = oci_execute($parse_result);
    oci_commit($conn);
    oci_close($conn);
    }
 }
```

plz guide me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you just have to remove the `while` loop.

Here's a rewrite of your code applying that change (+ you use too many parenthesis, decreasing your code readability + you should use SQL binding to avoid injection):

```
$query_ora_update = "UPDATE app.ITEM_INFO SET ITEM_FLAG= 'Y', LAST_UPDATE_DATE = sysdate WHERE ITEM_FLAG = 'N'";
$parse_result = oci_parse($conn, $query_ora_update);
$result = oci_execute($parse_result);

oci_commit($conn);
oci_close($conn);
```

Comment: Hi Frosty, I tried as per you suggested but it seems that code is not executing from if() statement...

Comment: It displays like this-: ( [0] => FXQV2 [ITEM_NAME] => ABC12 [1] => CA [SITE_CODE] => CA )

Comment: Ok. As Oswaldo suggested, the `if` conditions on code & sku doesn't seems useful since you already have constraints in your `UPDATE` query => edited my answer (+ added `ROWNUM = 1` on the 1st query)

Comment: Ok...but I want to check for all items app.ITEM_INFO table..but we are just providing rownum =1 so how to use in such a way that it will move for next row & when it found entry, update query will  work...

Comment: So... why don't you only do the `UPDATE` query using only the constraint `WHERE ITEM_FLAG = 'N'`? => updated answer

Answer (score 2):

To fetch a single row in Oracle, add in your where clause the following condition:

```
ROWNUM = 1
```

Unfortunately could not understand the rest of your code, did not understand why the "ifs" if you already have the same condition in the where clause of your update.

Comment: Hi Oswaldo, How to use the same if I want to use the same untill next match in that table & if it founds that entry it will fire update query given in my code.

Comment: If you want to update all records from the table ITEM_INFO that have   ITEM_FLAG = 'N' & SITE_CODE = $code & ITEM_NAME = $sku, you do not have go through all lines making this update, sql below would do it for you. I still can not understand what you are trying to do :p

`UPDATE
    APP.ITEM_INFO
SET
    ITEM_FLAG = 'Y',
    LAST_UPDATE_DATE = sysdate
WHERE
    ITEM_NAME = '$sku'
AND SITE_CODE = '$code'
AND ITEM_FLAG = 'N'`

Comment: HI Oswaldo, In ITEM_INFO table there are NO. of items having different site_code & flag as 'N'. So whatever $sku(item_name) & $code(site_code) are coming from my code in that variable, I want to match the same with ITEM_INFO table & if it matches need to update flag as 'Y'. SO I need the logic in such away that if $sku & $site_code didn't match with first row of ITEM_INFO, it must check with next row likewise...

Answer (score 2):

The Oracle equivalent to mysql_fetch_assoc is [oci_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-assoc.php) :)

```
$parsed = ociparse($conn, $sql);
while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($parsed))
{
    // your logic here
}
```