# Multiple sessions depending on type of login?

Tags: php, oracle, session, oracle-apex

What I've attempted to do is make it so that when you log in to the website it will reference the type of account that is in the database and depending on the type it will set the session variable then it will link you to the appropriate page which will work with that session login. The issue I'm having is that no matter what it just sends me to back to the login page which should only occur for the else condition which is for when a user type is not detected. I'm using Oracle APEX database and I'm not sure why this is happening so any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php 

//include connection to titan
include 'oci_connect.php';
session_start();


$query_str = "SELECT type_of_Account FROM User_Account WHERE user_name = '".$_POST["Username"]."' AND PASSWORD = ('".$_POST["Password"]."')";

$stid =oci_parse($connection, $query_str);
oci_execute($stid);

$type =$info['type_of_Account'];

if($type == "Customer")
{
    $_SESSION['type']=1;
    //redirect to user page where it will be found through matching the user id and only display their details, can only be accessed if logged in
    echo '<script>window.location="user.php"</script>'; 
}
elseif($type == "Trader")
{
    $_SESSION['type']=2;
    //redirect to traders page where it will display the traders details and only theirs, only accessed if logged in with specific account type
echo '<script>window.location="trader.php"</script>';

}
elseif($type == "Admin")
{
    $_SESSION['type']=3;
    //redirect to admin page where they can view and edit all details, only one account type acceptable
    echo '<script>window.location="admin.php"</script>';


}
else {
    //Return to login page as login details are invalid
    echo '<script>window.location="login.html"</script>';

}

?>
```

This is my user page which is meant to be session 1:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['type']!=1){
    echo '<script>window.location="login.html"</script>';
}
?>
```

This is my traders page which is meant to be session 2:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['type']!=2){
    echo '<script>window.location="login.html"</script>';
}
?>
```

This is my admin page which is meant to be session 3:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['type']!=3){
    echo '<script>window.location="login.html"</script>';
}
?>
```

Comment: did you start the session?

Comment: @fred-ii- I start the session in the pages that it is supposed to be redirected to, I didn't think I started the session on this page right?

Comment: `session_start();` must reside inside all pages using sessions.

Comment: chances are, you've something above your page(s), HTML etc. which is causing that. Or, it's something else. A space before your opening PHP tags, a byte order mark etc. Edit: You've deleted your comment about headers already sent.

Comment: @fred-ii- I've added the opening few lines for all of the pages that it directs to into my main code as far as I can tell there's no errors edit: sorry I thought the headers thing was my issue that I could fix & deleted too hastily

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['type']) && ($_SESSION['type']!=1)){...}` with `session_start();` inside all pages. That first body of code doesn't have it. `!==` with 2x `=` may not be/do what you think.

Comment: You'd also be better to user the inbuilt PHP [`header()`](http://php.net/header) function to redirect - `die(header("Location: PAGE_TO_GO_TO.php"));`

Comment: As far as I can tell the error is with my if statement or my retrieval of the type since it doesn't actually seem to be opening the correct pages that I want it to

Comment: it may have something to do with `$type =$info['type_of_Account'];` then. I don't know how to fetch in ORACLE, but you need to use a fetch/loop for that. In MySQL it's something like `while($type=fetch_row() ){$type =$info['type_of_Account']; }`

Comment: @fred-ii- that's my issue as well, I can do the fetch loop in MySQL but we have to do this task in oracle and I'm not sure how the syntax for it works

Comment: I'm sorry to say Matt, I won't be able to help you out there. I'm an MySQL guy. I added the relevant tag, in case someone will pick up on it.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-array.php see the examples in there Matt. I'm sure you'll figure it out ;-) and see this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/10227597/ the OP's got some code there. I found those while searching for "fetch array in oracle php sql"